# Вывести определенный элемент инфоблока Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Есть инофрмационная страница, контент вывводится через компонент news.detail, возникла необходимость ввыводе дополнительного контента, в этом же инфоблоке создал еще один элемент, но не получается вывести 2 элемента через компонент news.detail.
Подскажите можно как-то в компонент передать ID элемента который необходимо вывести??

Answer (score 1):

В настройках компонента есть поле `"ELEMENT_ID" => $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]`, Вам нужно вместо `$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]` подставить айди нужной вам записи, но только одной, так как компонент news.detail предназначен для вывода информации конкретной детальной новости.

Для отображения нескольких записей используется компонент news.list, который выводит список имеющихся элементов со ссылками на них, а сами элементы отображаются news.detail в который передается нужный id в переменной `$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]`.

Если все же вы хотите в рамках компонента news.detail вывести еще одну запись из этого инфоблока, то для получения информации о ней Вам нужно использовать [АПИ](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/).

Для получения списка элементов инфоблока использовать `CIBlockElement::GetList` ([дока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)). Полученные поля выводим так как необходимо.

Comment: "с его помощью айдишники передаем нужные айди в метод CIBlockElement::GetByID". Зачем это нужно делать??? Гетлист может получить все, что может и GetByID, а вот как - раз GetByID не может получить пользовательские свойства элемента.

Comment: Точно. Немного запутался.